# Angular 6 - ForkJoin has no exported member

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have updated to Angular 6 and I'm trying to use ForkJoin, so on my service I have:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';
```

But it's not recognising is and I'm getting:

```
...ForkJoin has no exported member
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: try import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin'

Comment: I've added the answer below for angular v6 and rxjs v6. Hope that'll help the question.
@FatehMohamed Check the answer. It's quite changed how the import is done

Comment: ohh, ok thank you, i haven't updated to the 6th version yet

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Change your import to -

```
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';
```

Rxjs 6, along with simpler import paths, have now more easy to use operator methods. You dont have to use the Observable patch now.

So Instead of :

```
return Observable.forkJoin( this.http.get('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'), this.http.get('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users') );
```

You can simply use :

```
return forkJoin(this.http.get('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'), this.http.get('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

RxJS 6 has new and simpler import paths and gets away with chainable operators in favor of pipeable operators. This makes the library as a whole more tree-shakable and will result in smaller bundles.

Change your import as below and it should work

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
```

---

Few more examples on rxjs when upgrading to angular

```
// creation and utility methods
import { Observable, Subject, pipe } from 'rxjs';
// operators all come from `rxjs/operators`
import { map, takeUntil, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Answer source - [Upgrading and Summary of New Features](https://alligator.io/angular/angular-6/)

Comment: I'm tried that but Observable doesn't know forkJoin? - retrieveSeveral() {
    return Observable.forkJoin(
      this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'),
      this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      );
  }

Comment: I see the answer is accepted. Could solve the issue mentioned in the comment? @Craig2018

Comment: Well, you answered my question although my code is not working for some other reason: retrieveSeveral() { return Observable.forkJoin( this.http.get('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'), this.http.get('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users') ); }

Answer (score -1):

service.ts:

```
   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
   import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   getDetails(){
    let url1 ="../assets/sample.json";
    let url2 ="../assets/sampledata.json";
    //return this.http.get(url);
    return forkJoin(this.http.get(url1),
     this.http.get(url2));  
   }
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonServiceService } from './common-service.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  second: any;
  title = 'app';
  mydata:any;
  constructor(private service: CommonServiceService) {} 
  ngOnInit(){

    this.service.getDetails().subscribe(data=>{
      this.first= data[0];
      console.log(this.mydata);
      this.second = data[1];
      console.log(this.second);
    })
  }
}
```